# Running a binary through PATH gives no stack trace while running with absolute path gives the right stack trace

Tags: linux, bash, stack-trace

I have a binary, let's say foo. I built it with debug symbols, so I get the right stacktrace when crashing (I use boost stacktrace util):

$ the/file/path/foo
... the right stack trace ...

But if I include "the/file/path" into PATH and run the binary, it spits a stack trace without symbols:
$ foo
... empty stack trace ...

Sorry that I couldn't put the exact stack trace here since it's confidential, but I thought this problem itself is orthogonal to the exact stack trace. Is there any difference in how the executable is handled in two cases?

I tried a couple things, did objdump to see the debug symbols and obviously they are there, as it can be seen from the first case. I tried "hash -r" to clear the bash hash but didn't help, and I think those two cases are pointing the same binary anyway. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your binary using the stack, for instance by including a `system` command to run another executable?

Comment: just a thought - does `which foo` show the/file/path/foo? Possibly you have another `foo` in you path?

Comment: No, my binary doesn't run another executable. And yes, `which foo` shows `the/file/path/foo`. Still a big mystery, feels like chasing a ghost. :)